# Including a chunk of code in a shell script

Tags: bash

I have a number of shell scripts that all look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Dropbox/cms_sites/examplesite/media
sass -C --style compressed --update css:css

cd ~/Dropbox/cms_sites/examplesite

rm -f ./cache/*.html
rm -fr ./media/.sass-cache/
rm -fr ./admin/media/.sass-cache/


rsync -auvzhL . username@host:/home/username/remote_folder
```

(I know the use of cd seems weird, but they have evolved!)

Now, all these scripts have a few differences, in that they have different usernames, hosts, local folder and remote folder names, and I want an inexperienced user to be able to run them without arguments (so he can drag and drop them into a terminal without issue).

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Dropbox/cms_sites/examplesite/media
sass -C --style compressed --update css:css

cd ~/Dropbox/cms_sites/examplesite

include ~/scripts/common.sh

rsync -auvzhL . username@host:/home/username/remote_folder
```

then have a file in common.sh that looks like:

```
rm -f ./cache/*.html
rm -fr ./media/.sass-cache/
rm -fr ./admin/media/.sass-cache/
```

so that I can easily change sections of the code in lots of scripts at once.

Is this possible, or is there a better way to do this without using arguments and having one script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `source` command. It's bash's version of 'include'

Comment: It also has implications that should cause one to hesitate before suggesting it.

Comment: Indeed. But he asked explicitly for 'include'.

Comment: Of course, source is likely the way to go. As shown above, I want that file to run in the context of the current script, which I think source will do. I'll try it. What are the implications Ignacio?

Comment: @Rich among others, be careful *not* to end the source-d script with 'exit'; you'll terminate the source-ing script. And since the source-d script runs in the same context, doing environment changes (setting shell variables, changing directories, etc) affects the source-ing script.

Comment: Another one I just noticed is make sure you are same directory at the end of that script as you are the the start...

Comment: @Rich nothing that you can't solve with a pair of `pushd` and `popd` :)

Comment: Yep, that's what I went for. Really need to think before running scripts though, or at least copying the environment to another place before running it!

Answer (score 1):

No need for "include" if the script is executable:

```
~/scripts/common.sh
```

If the script is not executable or does not have an appropriate shebang line then you'll need to specify the interpreter:

```
bash ~/scripts/common.sh
```